# cambiar valor de inputs simultaneamente al modificar uno de ellos

Tags: javascript, entrada, onkeyup

En el siguiente codigo quiero que al modificar cualquiera de los 2 inputs cambie el otro con su respectiva operación pero tomando la variable del que se acaba de editar.

```js
  function calcular()
  {
     var valor1=  parseFloat( document.getElementById("valor1").value); 
     var valor2=  parseFloat( document.getElementById("valor2").value);                           
     var valor3= document.getElementById("valor2").value = (4000*valor1)/2.25;  
     var valor4= document.getElementById("valor1").value = (3.56*valor2)/4000;  
  }
```

```html
<input type=text  id="valor1" onKeyUp="calcular();" />
<input type="text" id="valor2"  onKeyUp="calcular();" >
```

osea que al editar el campo "**`valor1`**" automáticamente el campo "**`valor2`**" sea: `(4000*valor1)/2.25`  sin que "**`valor1`**" cambie también y viceversa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas pasar la referencia del input que estas modificando.  Quedaria asi:

```js
function calcular(input)
  {
     var id = input.id;
     if (id == "valor1") {
       document.getElementById("valor2").value = (4000*input.value)/2.25; 
     } else {
       document.getElementById("valor1").value = (3.56*input.value)/4000;  
     }
  }
```

```html
<input type=text  id="valor1" onKeyUp="calcular(this);" />
<input type="text" id="valor2"  onKeyUp="calcular(this);" >
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.. en uso!

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero realizar dos funciones, mandas a llamar el evento `onKeyUp` según en el `input` en el que te ubiques, te dejo el ejemplo con los mismos valores que utilizaste para que quede más claro:

```js
function calcular()
  {
     var valor1=  parseFloat( document.getElementById("valor1").value);                          
     var valor3= document.getElementById("valor2").value = (4000*valor1)/2.25;  
  }
  
  
  function calcularDos()
  {
     var valor2=  parseFloat( document.getElementById("valor2").value);                           
     var valor4= document.getElementById("valor1").value = (3.56*valor2)/4000;  
  }
```

```html
<input type=text  id="valor1" onKeyUp="calcular();" />
<input type="text" id="valor2"  onKeyUp="calcularDos();" >
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: gracias amigo!!

Comment: Un placer compañero. Saludos.